# MobaXterm ssh console not showing correct character in tree command

Tags: putty, console, utf-8, characters, mobaxterm

When in Linux SSH box, using MobaXterm, I enter tree command, the output is:

```
âââ jboss
  âââ gc.log.0.current
  âââ server.log
```

which should be:

```
└── jboss
  ├── gc.log.0.current
  └── server.log
```

In Putty, the problem can be fixed with settings (`PuTTY Configuration` > `Window` > `Translation` > `Remote character set:` > `UTF-8`), but there is no corresponding settings in MobaXterm. Setting `Settings` > `Configuration`> `Terminal` > charset to `UTF-8 (Unicode)` has no effect.

How do I get MobaXterm to show correct characters?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that global settings makes default settings for new sessions and has nothing to do with the saved sessions settings.

To correct the problem I had to correct the char settings via edit-session for the saved session and not the settings - configuration.